# How can I tell if I have Google Chrome 64-bit installed?

Tags: google-chrome

I *think* I just installed Chrome 64-bit, but I can't tell.  About Google Chrome screen shows only *Version 37.0.2062.94 m* and I don't have anything in my 64-bit Program Files folder.  Is there a way to tell if I am using 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know which build of Chrome I'm running, 32bit or 64bit? How do I change it](http://superuser.com/questions/804222/how-do-i-know-which-build-of-chrome-im-running-32bit-or-64bit-how-do-i-change)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you open task manager you should see (32 bit) beside the executeable name if it's 32 bit, and nothing if it's 64 bit.

Comment: You are correct.  It turns out that it never even installed.  The "close all instances of Chrome" window was still open in the background =\.  After I installed it, I checked and the `*32` was gone.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it through task manager as CammRobb suggested (works for all programs) or in Chrome go to the About Google Chrome page (type in the adress bar `chrome://help/` or `chrome://chrome/`) and you will see the version and the architecture.

[image: How to find out if Google Chrome 32 or 64 bit]

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because this works on multiple platforms (and is simpler).  The accepted answer is specific to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Start the Task Manager (shortcut: ctrl+shift+esc). Lookup Chrome.exe in the process list. If "(*32)" is behind the process name, it's 32 bits. If there is nothing, it's 64 bits.

Tested on Win7 with Chrome 32 and 64 bits.