# How do I know which build of Chrome I'm running, 32bit or 64bit? How do I change it

Tags: google-chrome, windows

Recently, Google has provided a 64bit build for Windows. How do I know which build I'm running and how do I change it? I want to try it and be able to go back if I need to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe closing the older question as a duplicate of this one would be better because this one has the "How do I change it" part. (related meta question: [Should older questions be flagged as duplicates of more recent ones if those have better answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6924/194694))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click Menu button → *About Google Chrome*. It will say something like:

> Version 38.0.2125.24 dev-m (64-bit)

`stable-m` means that you're running regular, stable build. There's also `beta-m`, `dev-m` (quite less stable than beta, but updated more often) and `canary-m` (very unstable, but updated very often).

64-bit versions have *(64-bit)* at the end.

To switch to another channel (either switch between 32/64-bit or between stable/beta/dev), go to [Chrome Release Channels website](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) and download appropriate version.

Switching to more stable channel can be problematic, so think twice before you install beta-m or dev-m. Installing canary-m is relatively safe because it installs alongside regular Chrome (other editions replace each other), but canary is *very* unstable, so I don't recommend it.

Switching between 32/64-bit stable-ms is safe.

Answer (score 1):

To know which version you are running open Task Manger (ctrl+shift+esc) and if it's the 32bit version it will have (32 bit) beside it, if it's 64 bit, it won't have anything next to it.