# Installed Google Chrome 64 bit, but am I launching the 32 or 64 bit version?

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, 64-bit

I installed Chrome 64 bit, but am I running the 64 bit version?

I went to Control Panel\System and Security\System to confirm that I'm running an 64 bit version of Windows on an x64 bit processor.

I don't have a folder C:\Program Files\Google, but I do have a folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application.

When I to go task manager, I see that Google Chrome (32 bit) is running.

When I go to Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features, I only Google Chrome listed one time.

This is the 2nd computer that I'm seeing this on.

Comment: **You can tell by the name of the process.**  If the 32-bit process is running then your running the 32-bit process.  Part of the steps to install 64-bit chrome is to get rid of the 32-bit installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know which build of Chrome I'm running, 32bit or 64bit? How do I change it](http://superuser.com/questions/804222/how-do-i-know-which-build-of-chrome-im-running-32bit-or-64bit-how-do-i-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened with me as well. Confirm that you downloaded the correct installer (64bit). Then quit Chrome completely and restart it. Go to the settings menu (hamburger icon) > About Chrome (chrome://chrome/). Under the version number, there will be a message about an update and a button that says "Relaunch." Click on that button to update Chrome properly.

When you go on the page after this, the version number should say "Version 37.0.x (64-bit)". I believe this happens because Chrome doesn't really close itself and keeps running in the background, so a manual relaunch is required to make the switch.

Comment: They need to make this process more clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Hoppe Sure! How's it running BTW? It was causing my system to slow down, disk usage shot to 100% for some reason so I've rolled back to 32-bit.

Comment: No noticeable degradation. I haven't monitored the task manager closely, but a quick check now seemed like it was ok @wzub

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, if the version numbers do not match (example: 32-bit is Chrome 38.x and 64-bit is 37.x) you will need to uninstall the 32-bit version and create a new profile.

If you are using Chromesync, then restoring all your old info shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then when you got to the setting scroll down to the end of the page and after that click on information and you can see about the detail of your device if it's 64 bit I think it would be ok to download each you wanted to.

Comment: Note that the asker has already established his OS is 64 bit! See the second line in his question. He was trying to figure out how to both install and launch 64 bit *Chrome*.